# facebook app requests notifications doesn't appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Actually I need to add the app requests concept in my app. For that I have used following code :

```
     [FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
     message:@"Try this app"
     title:nil
     parameters:params
     handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
         } else {
             if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
                 if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                     NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                 } else {
                     NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                     NSLog(@"Request ID: %@", requestID);
                 }
             }
         }
     }];


  - (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query 
    {
 NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
    NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *val =
    [kv[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    params[kv[0]] = val;
  }
  return params;

 }
```

I also looked upon this facebook documentation [App requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/#frictionless_requests)

But when I send request to any of my friend, I got the request id but that notification doesn't appear on my friend facebook account. What I am doing wrong with above code?

Answer (score 1):

Requests are not shown in notifications. There are only viewable in private by the user they are sent to. The will show up on the Requests page or as a notification to the user.

Comment: Notifications doesn't appearing on Facebook friends account @Kanhaiya Sharma

Comment: Yes @Kanhaiya Sharma .. it is showing in app center.. But can't we get notification.. ?

Comment: @MinkleGarg we have tried much more about this but can't show notifications(related to app request)

Comment: it is final suggestion from my side

Comment: I have done more R&D that we can have notifications by add the App on facebook in facebook app settings. And it is working fine. By the way really thanks to share your knowledge with me.

Comment: @MinkleGarg I am also having same issues, can you please explain why do you mean by add the App..and how to do this...do you mean to say adding the app to appcenter? we have a website instead that use fb app login.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are asking but it is a bit of a hassle. 
There is nothing wrong with your request code from what I can see.

But what you probably don't have - and need is to add an "App on Facebook" in your settings page for your app.

It is where you have added "iOS" as a platform. You need to add "App on Facebook" as a platform as well and for this you will need 2 things. A website url (any site you control)  and a url which is protected by https.

Once you have this and put this into "Canvas URL" and "Secure Canvas URL" in the Facebook settings the notifications sent by the app will show up on the home-screen for the tergeted user(s).

Answer (score 0):

you Set enable in sandbox mode in facebook developer

Here's Visit   https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fapps

In your Facebook go to games->apps->app request and see app notification